# Android TableLayout - add buttons dynamically at center of screen

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Please see below screenshot for different results on tablet and on phones.

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
android:weightSum="4"
android:padding="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/crossword_background"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/count_frame"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#5A0FC8"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_score"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/count_frame"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#5A0FC8"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="4" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ShowHint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ShuffleButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_360"
                android:background="@null"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        </TableLayout>


    </RelativeLayout >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_divider"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/leftLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            >

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

background_ic_btn_bonus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_bonus"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="center" >
</bitmap>
```

background_ic_btn_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_default"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="center" >
</bitmap>
```

Corresponding Java Code

```
    String[] iLayoutMap = getTableLayout();
    /*
    iLayoutMap contains split rows removing 2 
    2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0*/
    TableLayout tableLayout  = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);

    for(int i=1;i<iLayoutMap.length;i++){
        TableRow NewRow1 =new TableRow(this);
        NewRow1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        NewRow1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        NewRow1.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        NewRow1.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        String [] items = iLayoutMap[i].split("\\s*,\\s*");
        NewRow1.setWeightSum(items.length-1);
        for(int j = 0; j < items.length;j++) {
            if(items[j].equalsIgnoreCase("0")){


                Button btnAdd = new Button(context);
                btnAdd.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                btnAdd.setTextSize(25);
                btnAdd.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                //btnAdd.setPadding(10   ,10,10,10);
                //btnAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_default);
                btnAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_ic_btn_default);
                btnAdd.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,1));
                NewRow1.addView(btnAdd);
            }else if(items[j].equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404582/adding-text-to-imageview-in-android



                Button btnAdd = new Button(context);
                String strId = Integer.toString(i) + Integer.toString(j-1);
                //btnAdd.setWidth(iObjectWidth);
                //btnAdd.setHeight(iObjectHeight);
                btnAdd.setId(Integer.valueOf(strId));
                btnAdd.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                btnAdd.setTextSize(25);
                btnAdd.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                //btnAdd.setPadding(10   ,10,10,10);
                //btnAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_default);
                btnAdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_ic_btn_bonus);
                btnAdd.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1 ));
                NewRow1.addView(btnAdd);
            }
        }
        NewRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,items.length-1));
        tableLayout.addView(NewRow1);
    }
```

Function

```
public String[] getTableLayout() {

    if (lvlinfo != null) {
        return lvlinfo.getLayout().split("2");
    }

    //Return this as default in case of failure
    String arr = "2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0";
    //String arr = "2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0";
    return arr.split("2");

}
```

Expected Result ( Working correctly on Tablet with Android 4.4.2 with below code)

[image]

Actual Results ( Tested on multiple phones with OS >= 8.1.0)
[image]

[image: Expected Result ( Working correctly on Tablet with Android 4.4.2 with below code with layout bounds)]

[image: Actual Results ( Tested on multiple phones with OS >= 8.1.0 without layout bounds)]

Comment: [You should use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58212584/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod - If we want to use tableview. Can you point out what is wrong with about solution? Why it works with 4 os and not on 8?

Comment: For me your code is working fine check the output [result in Oreo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwpHH.png) && 
[result in android pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RoG6.png) &&  [result in android Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9dqe.png)

Comment: @NileshRathod - is it issue with image i'm using? What is dimension of image used in your project?

Comment: I have used 64*64 png image

Comment: @NileshRathod tried using 64*64 image. Still different results on different OS

Comment: Please share parent layout of your `RelativeLayout` may be issue in your parent layout

Comment: @NileshRathod - Updated question with complete layout

Comment: Check the weights. With x items each having a weight of "1," the weights sum to x. You are setting the weight sum of the row to "x-1" and it should be "x" of just not set. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: @Cheticamp - I have already rechecked weights. They are correct. Length-1 is for additional value "2" which we get from split

Comment: I see now. You start from index "1" instead of zero. Still, an MCVE would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I Have tried your code but unable to reproduce this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOJGT.png)

For me your code is working fine check the output

- [Result in Oreo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwpHH.png)
- [Result in android pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RoG6.png)
- [Result in android Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9dqe.png)

as per my opinion you should use

You should use `RecyclerView` with [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Follow this sample code

> Add one recyclerview in your activity layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gridRecyclerView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Now inside your activity set `GridLayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView`

```
GridLayoutManager (Context context, 
                int spanCount)
```

Creates a vertical GridLayoutManager

**Parameters**

> **context  Context:** Current context, will be used to access resources.
>
> **spanCount    int:** The number of columns in the grid

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);
        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gridRecyclerView);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(JavaActivity.this, 6);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    }
}
```

> Create one adapter class `RecyclerView` like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position%2==0){
            holder.imgBanner.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }else {
            holder.imgBanner.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            holder.imgBanner.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 36;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgBanner;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgBanner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);

        }
    }
}
```

> Create one layout file for `RecyclerView` item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a padding like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="someDp"   ->>>> Padding
            android:paddingRight="someDp" ->>>> Padding
            android:layout_above="@+id/horizontal_divider"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:gravity="center">
    <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"></TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Try with Developer options -> Drawing -> Show layout bounds. There you can see what is what .What is the size of the table, the views in the table, the blue squares and you can realize what needs to be modified.